# How to prevent the Firefox developer tools window from focusing on page reload?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I've been annoyed by Firefox developer tools window always restoring from minimized state (focusing) every time the page I'm working on is reloaded.

I'm not sure if this is a quirk or a feature but it's sure annoying as hell.

I've observed this behavior in Firefox Developer Edition 69.0b16 as well as in standard Firefox release 67.0.4 running on Windows 10. Haven't tested other platforms but I might.

So far I've tried looking in the developer tools settings but there's nothing there. Reading all `devtools.*` items in `about:config` didn't turn up anything focus-related either.

Comment: Can you explain the first paragraph with some details?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I'm having the same issue as him: the Firefox DevTools, when undocked from the webpage (running on a separate window) and minimized/hidden behind other windows, brings up to the front of the screen everytime you navigate to a different section of (or refresh) the webpage you're debugging.

AndyDeGroo did you achieved to fix it?

Comment: @jesus I hadn't used Firefox in a while. Just checked on Firefox Developer Edition 72.0b11 on Windows 10 (10.0.18363.657) and it does not have this behaviour.

It would make sense to focus the developer tools window only while debugging and when the debugger stops on exception (if that is enabled) or hits a breakpoint in code.